Extracting Certificate Details (ID, ARN, PEM) and Keys Securely in Android for AWS IoT Core
I'm working on an Android application that interacts with AWS IoT Core for managing things. I have downloaded the following files:
An AWS IoT Core certificate (.pem extension)
Public key (.pem extension)
Private key (.pem.key extension)
I need to securely extract the following information from the certificate file within my Android application:
Certificate ID (Serial Number)
Certificate ARN (Amazon Resource Name)
Certificate PEM (entire encoded data)
Security Concerns:
I understand that storing the private key directly on the device is a security risk. How can I achieve this while maintaining a secure approach?
Additional Context:
Are there any recommended libraries for parsing the PEM files?
Is there a way to retrieve the Certificate ARN from the certificate data itself, or do I need to fetch it from AWS IoT Core?
Any guidance on securely extracting this information and using the keys in my application would be greatly appreciated.
